# about os.system, keeping file open

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import os

path="C:\\apg.exe"

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path))

os.system(path)
```

Rrun this code, I got 1 as a result, and apg.exe just pops and disappear. I want to keep it open.

(I use python3.4.2 and my OS is Windows7)

Comment: 1 means there was an error (apg.exe crashed or something). Was there any error messages?

Comment: No, >>> os.system(path)
1

Comment: Have you tried running your code as a script (not interactive)

Comment: and the disappearing window was not apg.exe. it was some dos window.

Comment: no. I used Python 3.4.2 Shell.

Comment: I saved this code as test.py and run it, result was same. some dos window pops

Answer (score 0):

Try running with **cmd.exe** with **/K** option which after running command returns to command prompt so you should see some error prints from your tool or cmd shell (when e.g. file not found):

```
os.system('cmd.exe /K "C:\\apg.exe"')
```